# Unity gone fglrx Radeon HD 7790

Tags: unity, 13.04, fglrx

I just installed the proprietary driver for the Radeon HD 7790 OC following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI), using the 3rd step(building .deb from the AMD binary) because the Additional Drivers dialog doesn't suggest any drivers for me(I think the 7790 seems to use a different driver, since it also got its own category/series on the [AMD Site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx)  (Desktop Graphics -> Radeon HD -> Radeon HD 7790 PCIE). The Installation went without errors.
Anyway after I rebooted, the Unity environment is missing, I can still open windows through keybindings but that's it. All the fixes for a missing Unity(like resetting through compiz...) didn't work.

`fglrxinfo` output:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (ATIFGLEXTENSION)
Minor opcode of failed request:  66 ()
Serial number of failed request:  13
Current serial number in output stream:  13
```

This is my `xorg.conf` as generated by `aticonfig --initial`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
        Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
        Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This is on Ubuntu Raring btw.

Comment: When you change the volume with the keyboard or get a notification do you see a black square around the notification or is it transparent as it should be? If it is transparent resetting unity should work, try it a few times, it does not always work the first time. If there is a black box then the drivers are not loading properly, as you may have guessed. ;)

Comment: Also install synapse if you haven't already, it will help in launching apps while unity isn't working. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/synapse-gnome-do-launcher-app-review-ubuntu

Comment: I don't know the keybinding for volume controls(I don't have function keys on my keyboard) Anyway as I said, I tried resetting Unity and it didn't work, I think this is rather a problem with the driver/compatibility than with misconfiguration of Unity

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install HD7790 fglrx driver on ubuntu 13.04 AMD64 with Unity. This is no exact step by step - I am trying to remember which steps I did. I take no guaranty.

1. Remove fglrx drivers `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates xvba-va-driver`
2. Use the guide from http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide#Before_you_start (from install prerequisite to install created debs), I tried another driver to, but it work only with 13.4 http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
3. `rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` maybe you should do a backup, but I had a damaged config
4. `sudo amdconfig --initial -f`
5. `sudo reboot` # after startup it showed just desktop background nothing more
6. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
7. `glxgears` # no errors, more than 1400 FPS ... driver is installed and working
8. `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` # install ccsm
9. `ccsm` # run as standard usernot as root, in my case Unity plugin was disabled
10. Enable Unity plugin and confirm requests for enabling another modules and rewrite key bindings